# Proving a limit of a trigonometric function: $\lim_{x \to 2/\pi}\lfloor \sin \frac{1}{x} \rfloor=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, epsilon-delta, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{2}{\pi}}\lfloor \sin \frac{1}{x} \rfloor=0$$

[image]

I need to prove the limit of this using the $\epsilon - \delta $ way but I don't know how to find $\delta$ when I'm given a trigonometric function I know only how to do it with polynomial functions

Comment: You could instead look at it as the limit $$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin x.$$ This should help some.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Why can I do such a thing?

Comment: It is just a substitution, but it might not be clear to you since Cameron used the same variable. $x\mapsto\frac1{x}$.